# Python: Get dictionary keys as list sorted by sub dictionary value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have the following structure:

```
structure = {
    'pizza': {
        # other fields
        'sorting': 2,
    },
    'burger': {
        # other fields
        'sorting': 3,
    },
    'baguette': {
        # other fields
        'sorting': 1,
    }
}
```

From this structure I need the keys of the outer dictionary sorted by the `sorting` field of the inner dictionary, so the output is `['baguette', 'pizza', 'burger']`.

Is there a simple enough way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `list.sort()` method and the `sorted()` builtin function take a `key` argument, which is a function that's called for each item to be sorted, and the item is sorted based on the returnvalue of that keyfunction. So, write a function that takes a key in `structure` and returns the thing you want to sort on:

```
>>> def keyfunc(k):
...     return structure[k]['sorting']
...
>>> sorted(structure, key=keyfunc)
['baguettes', 'pizza', 'burger']
```

Comment: I did not forget `.keys()`, it isn't necessary. Dicts yield keys when you iterate over them.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `sorted` builtin function.

```
sorted(structure.keys(), key = lambda x: structure[x]['sorting'])
```